# how to count appearance of || in string in redshift table

Tags: amazon-redshift

in regexp_count symbol | is used for alternative matches (a|b   It matches either a or b.). but if i have || in a string and i need to count its apearance, how can i do this? I have tried:

```
, REGEXP_COUNT(dcsis.value, '||')
, REGEXP_COUNT(dcsis.value, '|')
, REGEXP_COUNT(dcsis.value, chr(124)||chr(124))
, REGEXP_COUNT(dcsis.value, ''||''||''||'')
, REGEXP_COUNT(replace(dcsis.value, '||', '/'), '/')
```

but inly tha last one gives correct result but i don't like this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `||` together would not occur as part of some larger sequence of pipes, you could keep it simple and use a replacement trick:

```sql
SELECT value, (LEN(value) - LEN(REPLACE(value, '||', ''))) / 2 AS num_or
FROM dcsis
```